# Kendoui higri datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

As per the link and the code given below you can see that I defined the culture for the date picker to be ar-SA which is the Hijri date.

You can see that it is getting the wrong today date and year. How can I fix this>

It should get 1435 but it gets 2013 in the footer and the initial date.

http://jsfiddle.net/zvjWe/786/

```
kendo.culture("ar-SA");

$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
   format:"d/M/yyyy",
   min:new Date(1300,0,1)
});
```

Comment: I don't see easy way out, there is no date conversion logic in the kendo.culture.ar-SA.js, ideally you need to include the date conversion and extend the default culture file.( 1435 - is 2013 http://www.islamicity.com/prayertimes/defaulthijriconv.asp)

Comment: i think it is a bug on there side. thanks for your reply but how to extend it.